# HTML forms not connecting as one

Tags: html, angularjs

I have only one form group. A submit button will only enable if all the form inputs are valid. Yet the submit button already enables halfway through completion. When I try to declare another form tag with the same id, the other half works but the previous half don't. I don't know the proper position of form tags plus I use many  tags because of the bootstrap grids.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
  <!--MAIN PANEL-->
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="pheading">Create</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <form name="formCreate" novalidate>
          <!--NAME-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Name</legend>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="fields" align="middle">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="ctrl.person.name" ng-minlength="10" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </fieldset>
            </div>

            <!--BDAY-->
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Birthday</legend>
                <div class="fields" align="middle">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="bday" ng-model="ctrl.person.birthday" required ng-date>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <!--GENDER-->
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Gender</legend>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="radios" align="middle">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" required><span>Male</span></label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" required><span>Female</span></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <!--MARITAL-->
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Marital Status</legend>
                <div class="row" align="middle">
                  <div class="fields" align="middle">
                    <div>
                      <select name="status" name="status" ng-model="ctrl.person.maritalStatus" required>
                      <option selected hidden>Select Status</option>
     <option value="Single">Single</option>
     <option value="Married">Married</option>
     <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
     <option value="Separated">Separated</option>
     <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
   </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
            <!--ADDRESS-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Address</legend>
                <div class="fields" align="middle">
                  <textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="50" form="formCreate" placeholder="Enter address..." align="middle" ng-model="ctrl.person.address" required></textarea>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>

            <!--TEL-->
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Telephone</legend>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="fields" align="middle">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter telephone number" align="middle" ng-model="ctrl.person.telephoneNumber" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <!--EMAIL-->
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <fieldset class="well">
                <legend align="left">Email</legend>
                <div class="fields" align="middle">
                  <div class="fields" align="middle">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="ctrl.person.emailAddress" required ng-email>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

        <!--SUBMIT-->

        <button ng-click="ctrl.submitPerson()" onClick="showModal()" class="btn btn-primary" id="sbtn" ng-disabled="formCreate.name.$invalid||formCreate.bday.$invalid||formCreate.gender.$invalid||formCreate.status.$invalid||formCreate.address.$invalid||formCreate.telephone.$invalid||formCreate.email.$invalid">Submit</button>

        <!--MODAL-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's literally no reason to use more than 1 form here.

Comment: my bad. I did that when I was debugging. But when I declare that second form tag there, the forms inside it works and the ones above doesn't anymore. and when I remove that second tag which would have hopefully solve the problem, the forms from address up to email doesn't work again. It's like the form tag doesn't know where to end it's scope.

Comment: Why would you not wrap everything in a single form element?

Comment: Yes you did edit it, but now the question does not make sense as asked.

Comment: but it was still not working before.

BUT IT'S WORKING NOW. I just used a simple trick! Inside the form tag. I just wrapped everything in a single div container. thanks for the help

Comment: You can just use `formCreate.$invalid` instead of all that complex conditional.

Comment: there is some lines of codes there that I have ommitted due. every input element has its own error message display above them

Answer (score 1):

Do a code walkthrough and check for the following:

1. Check and remove unused  tag
2. Place the end tags in proper place

This is a edited code, try this, hope it works!

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
   </div>
<!--MAIN PANEL-->
  <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="pheading">Create</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
  
  <form name="formCreate" novalidate>
<!--NAME-->
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Name</legend>
      <div class="row"> 
     <div class="fields" align="middle">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="ctrl.person.name" ng-minlength="10" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/">
    </div>
    </div>
    
              </fieldset>
    </div>
    
<!--BDAY-->
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Birthday</legend>
      <div class="fields" align="middle">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="bday" ng-model="ctrl.person.birthday" required ng-date>
      </div>
    </fieldset> 
    </div>
<!--GENDER-->    
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Gender</legend>
     <div class="row"> 
     <div class="radios" align="middle">
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" required><span>Male</span></label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" required><span>Female</span></label> 
      </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
<!--MARITAL-->    
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Marital Status</legend>
     <div class="row" align="middle">  
      <div class="fields" align="middle">
      <select name="status" name="status" ng-model="ctrl.person.maritalStatus" required>
      <option selected hidden>Select Status</option>
      <option value="Single">Single</option>
      <option value="Married">Married</option>
      <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
      <option value="Separated">Separated</option>
      <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </form>
            </div>
   
   <form name="formCreate" novalidate>
   <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-1">
   </div>
<!--ADDRESS-->
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Address</legend>
      <div class="fields" align="middle">
     <textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="50" form="formCreate" placeholder="Enter address..." align="middle" ng-model="ctrl.person.address" required></textarea> 
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    
<!--TEL-->    
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Telephone</legend>   
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="fields" align="middle">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter telephone number" align="middle"  ng-model="ctrl.person.telephoneNumber" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">
    </div>
    </div>
              </fieldset>    
    </div>       
<!--EMAIL-->    
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <fieldset class="well">
      <legend align="left">Email</legend>
    <div class="fields" align="middle">
      <div class="fields" align="middle">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control"
                    name="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="ctrl.person.emailAddress" required ng-email>      
    </div>
    </div> 
    </fieldset>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-md-1">
   </div>
   </div>
    
  </form>

<!--SUBMIT-->
  
  <button ng-click="ctrl.submitPerson()" onClick="showModal()" class="btn btn-primary" id="sbtn" ng-disabled="formCreate.name.$invalid||formCreate.bday.$invalid||formCreate.gender.$invalid||formCreate.status.$invalid||formCreate.address.$invalid||formCreate.telephone.$invalid||formCreate.email.$invalid">Submit</button> 
  
<!--MODAL-->  
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
 
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my problem is simple. just contain the contents of the form in a "div" first and enclose it in the "form" tag

```html
<form>
    <div class="form container">

         <!-- form elements -->
         
    </div>
</form>
```